# Retrieve the last record from an array with a condition in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an array of records in ansible as follow,

[ ami-abc;2020-11-08;false
ami-cdf;2020-11-09;false
ami-123;2020-11-10;false
ami-456;2020-11-11;true ]

I want to skip all the records with the trailing field value equal to true, and then retrieve the last record which has the trailing field value equal to false (in this case the record I want would be "ami-123;2020-11-10;false". Could anyone please give me advice on how to do this? I have tried a number of ways but nothing works unfortunately.

Thanks.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew. Welcome here. Can you update the question with your attempt ("*the number of ways*" you have tried)?

Comment: Can you please double check and eventually update your example data ? It does not look like a valid list, either in json or yaml format.

Answer (score 0):

Filter could be used to select the items which are matching your regex and in the newly created list the last item can be selected with [-1]

```
---
- name: Test stackoverflow
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    stacklist:
      - ami-abc;2020-11-08;false
      - ami-cdf;2020-11-09;false
      - ami-123;2020-11-10;false
      - ami-456;2020-11-11;true
    searchstring: "^(.*)false$"

  tasks:
  - name: Create a list of matching false elements
    set_fact:
      falselist: "{{ stacklist | select('match',searchstring) | list }}"

  - name: Debug the last item in the list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ falselist[-1] }}"
```

Comment: Hi GeorgiY, thanks very much for your suggestion. It works perfectly!

Comment: @AndrewLeung it has been my pleasure to contribute!